# How to update the values of an existing datalist jQuery Object?

Tags: html, jquery, html-datalist

The function addDataList() adds a datalist to an existing DOM (Input Text) element.

Example: Add some values:

```
addDataList('my_input',[1,2,3,4,5]);
```

If the datalist already exists, its options have to be removed and new options are to be added.

```
addDataList('my_input',[6,7,8,9,10]);
```

The first time addDataList() is called, the options are added and no error occurs.
The second call results in an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: datalist.appendChild is not a function

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function addDataList(i, a) {

    var id = i + "_datalist";
    var datalist = $('#' + id);
    if (datalist.length == 0) { // datalist does not exist
        var datalist = document.createElement('datalist');
        datalist.id =  id;
        document.body.appendChild(datalist);
    } else {
        datalist.html(''); // datalist exists, clear existing options
    }

    a.forEach(function (data) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text =   data;
        datalist.appendChild(option);
    });
    
    $('#' + i).attr('list', datalist.id).attr('autocomplete', 'off');

}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML please so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. datalist was a jQuery object.

```
function addDataList(i, a) {

    var id = i + "_datalist";

    var datalist = document.getElementById(id);
     
    if (!datalist) { // datalist does not exist
        var datalist = document.createElement('datalist');
        datalist.id =  id;
        document.body.appendChild(datalist);
    } else {
        datalist.innerHTML = '' // datalist exist, clear existing options
    }

    a.forEach(function (data) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text =   data;
        datalist.appendChild(option);
    });
    
    $('#' + i).attr('list', datalist.id).attr('autocomplete', 'off');

}
```